# Using iw to add a virtual wireless interface, getting the error “No such device (-19)”

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, embedded

I need to add a virtual wireless interface to my NXP embedded linux system using iw.

I have loaded Broadcom's driver and brought up wlan0.  I can connect to networks with the wifi SDIO adapter just fine.

This question has been asked before but they made an error in the command syntax.  I am not making the same error, but I receive the same results.

When I issue the command

> iw dev wlan0 interface add mySta type managed

or

> iw phy phy0 interface add mySta type managed

I receive the error "No such device (-19)".  wlan0 exists.  I see it when I run ifconfig.  phy0 exists.  I see it when I run "iw list".

The output from iw list suggests that this should be doable:

> root@imx_mfgtools_nogpu:~# iw list
>
> Wiphy phy0
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    Supported interface modes:
>              * IBSS
>              * managed
>              * AP
>              * P2P-client
>              * P2P-GO
>              * P2P-device
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   valid interface combinations:
>              * #{ AP } <= 1, #{ managed } <= 2, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ IBSS } <= 1,
>                total <= 4, #channels <= 2
> ```

How do I get a virtual interface up and running?

Thanks,
-Mike